# Toolbar overlapses when i try to apply theme

Tags: android, toolbar

I am using customs themes for my app, but when I select different theme my toolbar overlaps status bar. I can't Figure out what the problem is about.
Suggestions will be appreciated.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3944N.png)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".Activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app.popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <io.gloxey.cfv.CFTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:font_name="@string/sintony"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/placeholder_dialog" />
    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Theme of my Activity. I tried to set android:fitsSystemWindow:false, but it won't work.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: can you share the theme of your current activity?

Comment: see theme @AbdulKawee